# Faster way of taking a start and end timestamp and finding the number of seconds in between the two timestamps grouped by date?

Tags: python, pandas

#### Problem

Let's say I have two timestamps: **pandas.Timestamp("2021-08-21 23:00:00")** and **pandas.Timestamp("2021-08-23 10:00:00")**. I want to find out, in the time period between these timestamps, how many seconds are in 2021-08-21, 2021-08-22, and 2021-08-23? My code below works but it's really inefficient with large timestamp ranges.

---

#### Example

**Input**:

```
node = {'start': pd.Timestamp('2021-08-21 23:00:00'), 'end': pd.Timestamp('2021-08-23 10:00:00')}
```

**Output**:

```
{'2021-08-21': 3599, '2021-08-22': 86400, '2021-08-23': 35999}
```

---

#### Working code

```
import pandas as pd

node = {'start': pd.Timestamp('2021-08-21 23:00:00'), 'end': pd.Timestamp('2021-08-23 10:00:00')}

time_period = pd.date_range(node["start"], node["end"], freq="s", closed='left')
time_period.freq = None
time_period = time_period.tolist()

date_counts = {}
for timestamp in time_period:
    date = str(timestamp.date())
    if date not in date_counts:
        date_counts[date] = 1
    else:
        date_counts[date] += 1

print(date_counts)
```

---

#### Edits

**1)** I just realized there is an error in my code where it counts 23:00:00 to the end of the day as 3600 seconds rather than 3599.